# Testing REST service file upload and one text field using SoapUI

Tags: java, rest, soapui, jersey-2.0

I have developed a REST service using Jersey which looks like below

```
    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                                @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail, @FormDataParam("city") String city){
```

If I remove city String, then I am able to test file upload test in SoapUI by attaching the file with request.But, I am not able to test file upload along with String using SoapUI.

Comment: what error are you receiving when invokes `uploadFile` passing `city` param as string?

Comment: Can you please include a copy of your request from SoapUI?